# Error with ajax forms

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails

I have 2 forms and ajax script for them.

```js
jQuery("#mod-expert").submit(function () {
            var formNm = jQuery('#mod-expert');
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: '/notify',
                data: formNm.serialize(),
                success: function (data) {
                    // Вывод текста результата отправки
                    jQuery(".message").removeClass("hidden");
                    jQuery(".message-text").html(data);
                    jQuery(".overlay").removeClass("hidden");
                },
                error: function (jqXHR, text, error) {
                    // Вывод текста ошибки отправки
                    jQuery(".message").removeClass("hidden");
                    jQuery(".message-text").html(error);
                    jQuery(".overlay").removeClass("hidden");
                }
            });
            return false;
            });
```

```html
<div id="mod-order" class="form-modal">
      <div class="head-modal quest-head">ask question</div>
      <form id="mod-expert">
        <input type='hidden' name="header" value="quest <%= @expert.name %>">
        <div class="modal-fields">
          <div class="row">
            ....some inputs
          </div>
          <input type="hidden" name="info" id="info"/>
          <input type="hidden" name="field"/>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <input class="btn-send" type="submit" value="Отправить">
            <button class="btn-close">Отмена</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>

    <div id="mod-expert-block" class="form-modal">
      <div class="head-modal quest-head">Стать экспертом</div>
      <form id="mod-expert">
        <input type='hidden' name="header" value="Хочу стать экспертом">
        <div class="modal-fields">
          <div class="row">
            ...some inputs
          </div>
          <input type="hidden" name="info" id="info"/>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <input class="btn-send" type="submit" value="Отправить">
            <button class="btn-close">Отмена</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
```

But when I press submit in the 1st form GET query is sent. When we send 2nd form, it sends empty parameters, regardless of our inputs.
Although the similar form on another page to send the parameters properly.

Comment: Which version of jQuery are you using? The `type` property was only added in 1.9. The second form also has no event handler, so it will be submit in the standard manner. It also has no `action` attribute, hence the issue there.

Comment: That's a curious way to do things. Are you hand crafting that form? Why not use a form helper with `remote: true` and use your JS to respond to the `ajax:success` event?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan ver. 3.1.1. Exactly the same forms on the root page are sent normally without problems.
_jvillian it will be done later

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both of your forms have the same `id` value. This is why you're getting weird values being sent when submitting the forms.

As Rory mentioned in his comment, confirm that your version of jquery actually accepts the `type` parameter.